# SQL: Update stored procedure to update a table with composite primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a sql Table_A with three columns c1, c2 and c3. The c1 and c2 makes up the primary key for this table.

Now, the value of c1 is a primary in some other TableBB and I want to update a row in table A where c1 value matches with the parameter that was passed.

How can i do that. The code I am using is which gives me error

```
    create procedure sp_update
            @c1 char(20),
            @c3 char(20)
    AS

    UPDATE Table_A
            SET
            C3 = @c3
    WHERE C1 = @c1
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Table_A__85DC13D870B3A6A6'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table_A'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are there any **triggers** on that table?? When you're doing an `UPDATE` but you get an error about an `INSERT` - that seems a bit fishy....

Comment: @marc_s, m wondering myself as well, I use .update method but yet it gives me this error msg. I will have to look at it tomorrow, thanks for the input though..

Answer (score 0):

If your table is called "Table A", try:

```
UPDATE  [Table A]
```

Else, it looks like you're aliasing your table to "A".  But you can't alias in the `update` clause.  So change this:

```
UPDATE  YourTable A
```

to:

```
UPDATE  YourTable
```